# React project automatically export components by filename

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a fairly large project using react/webpack with a lot of components.
Currently my folder structure looks like this:

```
bin/
media/
src/
  components/
    login/
      Login.js
      LoginContainer.js
    registration/
    index.js
    ..
  framework/
  redux/
  ..
static/
test/
```

And in `src/components/index.js` I do the exports:  `export Login from ./Login/Login` so that in other components I can just do `import {Login, LoginContainer} from 'components'` without having to search the file location.

Is there a way to not have the exports in the index.js like now?
I'd like to export automatically all javascript files by their name, without having to type it every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add (all of) your Components-SubFolders to your [webpack.config.resolve](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) and just import the Filename.
Or just add the components root to [resolve.modulesDirectories](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) and import the Path relative to the components-folder.

Comment: But then I would have to import them as `import Login from 'components/login/Login'` no?
I would have like to keep importing like: `import {Login, LoginContainer} from 'components'`

Comment: if you use `webpack.config.resolve` not. just `import theFilesExport from 'FileName'`. alternatively you can usw `readdir-loader`